# Ajax success function works even if the there is no success

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
$something=100;
$.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "some.php",
          data: somevariable,
          dataType: "text",                  
          success: function(data) {         
            $something=$something-10; 
            alert($something);
          }.bind(this)
      });
```

Above ajax is used to fetch data from some.php file which is used to fetch data from mysql database. The file alerts a message when there is success or data retrieved from database but even if i stop mysql server and then again call the ajax then also it alerts the message with decrement in value of $something

So how can i make it work like if there is no row returned from database or empty row then there should be no success that is success only if there is some actual data returned from the database?

Comment: if u want, you can add error function for that

Comment: If your php script returns a 200 it will be always a success ajax call, you should return something different from the some.php file or check the result

Comment: Shutting down the database won't usually shut down the webserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:-

```
success: function (data) {
    // Checking data is not null or undefined and valid data is returned
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        $something = $something - 10;
        alert($something);
    }
}
```

Assuming that `data` is an array of data returned from server.

Also, to be safe use deferred `jqXHR.fail()` like

```
$.ajax("some_unknown_page.html")
.fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
    $('#post').html(msg);
});
```

This will help you to figure out the specific error that occurred while returning the data from server, and after that you can take appropriate action.

Or, as a simple example:-

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second complete" );
});
```

Comment: To quote the docs, "The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."

Comment: Umda Pradarshan. Kya Khoob Likha @palasH Ne. Umda.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
function fail() {
    alert("Fail!");
}
$something=100;
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "some.php",
      data: somevariable,
      dataType: "text",                  
      success: function(data) {
        if(!data) return fail();         
        $something=$something-10; 
        alert($something);
      }.bind(this)
  }).fail(fail);
```

You might need to check `data` more thoroughly depending on how it's formatted.

However, it's probably better if you can to get the server to not return a 200 (or another non-error code) if there's no data.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax success means that the ajax call was a success. In other words, it's a success because the ajax call reached the server and the server provided a response.
Use the 'data' field (the server's reaponse) to return information to the client, so that the client understands what happened. Anything goes: a code, a boolean, etc.